# How to create event from control's that not yet create?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

My program is the create datagridview program that user can create dynamic columns like row,column,panel(panel is quantity of the panel) so user can mark it too,
as I know I can mark the cell with CurrentCell.Style.BackColor

when I generate datagridview I have assign name of it But !!!!  it cant use the new datagridvieweventhandler command so I cant do any thing with each datagridview

so this is my Datagridview Generate Code

```
    string[] Panelname = { "One","Two","Three","Four","Five"};
    for(i=0;i<Panelname.length;i++){
    Generate(Panelname[i],a,b)}

    DataGridView generate(string name,int columns,int rows)
    {
        int i;
        Control Gen;
        Control LB;          
        LB = new Label();
        LB.Text = "Panel : "+name;
        LB.Location = new Point(50 + 120 / (c - 1) + 900 / c , 315);
        LB.BackColor = Color.Silver;
        Gen = new DataGridView();
        Gen.Name = name.ToString();
        Gen.Size = new Size(900/c,300 );            
        Gen.Location = new Point(120 / (c ) + 900 / c, 0);            
        DataGridView CH = (DataGridView)Gen;           
        CH.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        CH.CellClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(CH_CellClick);
        CH.Location = new Point(0+locate, 0);

        for (i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
        {
            CH.Columns.Add("", "");

        }
        for (i = 1; i < rows; i++)
        {

            CH.Rows.Add("", "");

        }

        dataGridView1.Controls.Add(LB);
        dataGridView1.Controls.Add(CH);

         return null;


    }
```

How can I create the event handler for each datagridview that I'm create it dynamicly ?

thankyou for your kind

Comment: why are you not able to use the `DataGrid` event handler?

Comment: As I know the event handler can be create
 when the object that have already create  but in this situation I still dont create it yet so it cant call eventhandler to use it

Comment: why do you want to call a eventhandler? i think you can call it, but normally it is triggered (by an event - as the name says)

Comment: I have to call eventhandler when I want the position of the cell to change the cell color  
EX. I have already create 5 datagridview and i want to show at text box that I click on the datagridview 1 I must call the One_Click event because now my program is cant seperate that which datagridview is choosing

sry that i have slow respond I'm not so good at english

Answer (score 1):

Create your datagridview.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    DataGridView d = new DataGridView();
    d.MouseClick += dataGridView_MouseClick;
}
```

Use the add handler method.

```
private void dataGridView_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Use sender to determine which datagridview fired the event
}
```

Comment: okay man that's work  the way that datagridview has been created by 

DataGridView d = new DataGridView(); 

so we can call the add handler method  but in my situation i didn't code that

DataGridView d = new DataGridView();  

because I must use the for loop to create it so it cant do it that way's

Comment: Actually you can ... a single event handler will handle the events for an unlimited number of controls.  That is why there is a sender parameter as the first parameter for most (if not all) event handlers in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I found is when I'm create datagridview in the datagridview it hard to define it what's datagridview that you're clicking so I have stuck in this problem for a while

And now I found out the way's to through out my problem now, here it is

for(i=0;i

```
    DataGridView generate2(string name, int columns, int rows,int form)
    {

        Control Gen;
        Control LB;
        int x = 1;
        int runcolumn = columns;
        int runrow = rows;
        int count=0;

        LB = new Label();
        LB.Text = "Panel : " + name;
        LB.Location = new Point(50 + 120 / (c - 1) + 900 / c, 320);
        LB.BackColor = Color.Silver;
        Gen = new DataGridView();
        Gen.Name = name.ToString();
        Gen.Location = new Point(120 / (c) + 900 / c, 0);
        DataGridView CH = (DataGridView)Gen;
        CH.RowTemplate.Height = 290 / rows;
        CH.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        CH.Size = new Size(900 / c, 300);
        CH.RowHeadersWidth = 10;
        CH.ColumnHeadersHeight = 10;            
        CH.Location = new Point(0 + locate, 0);
```

And********* CH.Click += new EventHandler(control_click);********* this is my hero's

```
    private void control_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is DataGridView)
        {
            DataGridView A = (DataGridView)sender;
            textBox2.Text = A.CurrentCell.RowIndex.ToString();
            textBox1.Text = A.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex.ToString();
            textBox3.Text = A.Name.ToString();
        }
    }
```

in the send control click function you can find what's kind of your control and cast it , so whatever control that you click it you can set it's function now!